# How to detect screen lock (Qt5, C++, Windows, OSX)

Tags: windows, macos, qt5

In my Qt5 C++ client, I'm wanting to detect when a user running Windows or OSX has locked the screen, then simultaneously lock my client application.

I have yet to come across a Qt5 class that provides this function, so I'm wondering if I'll need to write an OS-specific library.  Does anyone have any experience doing something like this?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you *"lock an OS"*?

Comment: Windows: WindowsKey+L
OSX: Ctrl+Shift+Eject

Comment: Oh, lock the screen!

Comment: You're right, that could be misinterpreted. Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, `Qt` doesn't provide listeners for session events. You'll have to code each for each platform you intend to use your app on.

Comment: Try http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#commitDataRequest and QSessionManager, maybe you can find something usefull.

Answer (score 1):

On windows you can use below code:

mywidget.cpp

```
#include "mywidget.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WtsApi32.h>
#include <QDebug>

MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    WTSRegisterSessionNotification((HWND)this->winId(), NOTIFY_FOR_THIS_SESSION);
}

MyWidget::~MyWidget()
{
    WTSUnRegisterSessionNotification((HWND)this->winId());
}

bool MyWidget::nativeEvent(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, long *result)
{
    if (eventType != "windows_generic_MSG") return false;

    MSG *msg = static_cast<MSG*>(message);
    switch (msg->message) {
    case WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE:
        qDebug() << "session change: " << msg->wParam;
    }
    return false;
}
```

project.pro

```
...
LIBS += -lwtsapi32
...
```

[reference1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsregistersessionnotification)
[reference2](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#nativeEvent)

Comment: its working for me